# How do I check if this is spelled correct letter by letter?

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting

In this code you "randomly" fill your array with letters and if it hits the word you are looking for returns the amount of trys to get it correct. What I want to implement is a way of checking if it is spelled correct from the first character going onwards. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {
    char *search= "SOMETHING";
    int clk = clock();
    printf ("clk=%d\n",clk);
    
    srand(clk);

    int len = strlen(search);
    char *tafel = (char *) malloc (len+1);
    tafel[len] = 0;
    int pos;
    char letter;
    long i=0;
    char check;

    while (strcmp (search,tafel) != 0 ) {
        i++;
        letter = rand() % 26 +'A';
        pos    = rand() % len;
        //pos=(pos+1)%len;
        tafel[pos] = letter;
        if (i%10000000==0) {
            printf("%4ld mio: %s\n", i / 1000000, tafel);
            printf ("%d\n",strcmp (search,tafel));
        }


    }


    printf("It takes %ld trys to find '%s'\n",i,tafel);
    printf ("%d\n",strcmp (suchwort,tafel));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on the desired method here. If any characters match, do you get to keep them and shuffle remaining letters, or do you shuffle the whole string on every time, or do you only proceed one letter at a time from the start to the end until each letter matches...?

Comment: Why not `srand(clock());` -> `srand(time(NULL))`?

Comment: `int len = strlen(search)+1;  /* space for terminating zero */`

Comment: @infixed OP's original code is better. Notice the `+ 1` in the `malloc` code and the `tafel[len] = 0;`. With your change, the latter would be UB without OP's `+1`. Otherwise, your code would allocate one too many.

Comment: if(tafel[j % 6] == 'C') {if (tafel[j % 6] == 'O') {if (tafel[j % 6] == 'R') {if (tafel[j % 6] == 'O') { if (tafel[j % 6] == 'N') {if (tafel[j % 6] == 'A') {break;
}else{j = 0; }}else{ j = 0 ;}else{ j = 0;} }else{ j = 0;} }else{ j = 0; }}else{j = 0;}
Sorry for shitty format but this is the base concept but I would prefer a more modular approche

Comment: You can _edit_ your question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66161688/edit and post the code from your comment in an additional code block. A `switch/case` might be better than an `if/else` ladder (e.g.) `switch (tafel[j % 6]) { case 'O': ... break; case 'R': ... break; }`

Comment: You mean to randomly guess the characters one at a time starting from the first and moving further only when the character is found?